# Flutter change all raised button text color in theme

Tags: flutter

I would like all my `RaisedButton` widgets to have a different `textColor`, how do I change only this in the `MaterialApp ThemeData`?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1b87f558d5b2d40c79de972a99bbe75e3cc8fb42/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/material_button.dart#L334), you'll see that it uses the method [`getTextColor()`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1b87f558d5b2d40c79de972a99bbe75e3cc8fb42/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button_theme.dart#L578) from `ButtonThemeData`, and this method considers the enum `ButtonTextTheme` to define the text color. The enum entries are `normal`, `accent` and `primary`. You can set a global text color for your `RaisedButton`s based on those colors, merely.

To implement that:

```dart
ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

return MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: theme.copyWith(
    buttonTheme: theme.buttonTheme.copyWith(
      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent,
    ),
  ),
);
```

If you want to set a custom color that doesn't match `normal`, `accent` or `primary`, the best option you got is creating a custom `Widget` with this color, so you don't need to set it in every `RaisedButton` individually.

Check it out:

```dart
class ButtonWithCustomTextColor extends RaisedButton {
  ButtonWithCustomTextColor({
    Key key,
    @required VoidCallback onPressed,
    ValueChanged<bool> onHighlightChanged,
    ButtonTextTheme textTheme,
    // Place your custom color here
    Color textColor = Colors.blue,
    Color disabledTextColor,
    Color color,
    Color disabledColor,
    Color highlightColor,
    Color splashColor,
    Brightness colorBrightness,
    double elevation,
    double highlightElevation,
    double disabledElevation,
    EdgeInsetsGeometry padding,
    ShapeBorder shape,
    Clip clipBehavior = Clip.none,
    MaterialTapTargetSize materialTapTargetSize,
    Duration animationDuration,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(
    key: key,
    onPressed: onPressed,
    onHighlightChanged: onHighlightChanged,
    textTheme: textTheme,
    textColor: textColor,
    disabledTextColor: disabledTextColor,
    color: color,
    disabledColor: disabledColor,
    highlightColor: highlightColor,
    splashColor: splashColor,
    colorBrightness: colorBrightness,
    elevation: elevation,
    highlightElevation: highlightElevation,
    disabledElevation: disabledElevation,
    padding: padding,
    shape: shape,
    clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
    materialTapTargetSize: materialTapTargetSize,
    animationDuration: animationDuration,
    child: child,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a light-themed app but wants white text on buttons, you can adjust the `buttonTheme` in your app's entry point (i.e. where you declare your `MaterialApp`). Something like:

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    buttonTheme: ThemeData.dark().buttonTheme
  ),
);
```